# Calling Dynamic controls from a seperate class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to know if it is possible to call a control and also attach it's events from a class. I have been researching the internet for a some valuable information but to no avail. Below is a simple illustration of what I intend achieving.

PAGE

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        DynamicControls(IsPostBack);
     }         

public void DynamicControls(bool posting_back)
{
    ControlHandler ch = new ControlHandler();

        CreateTextbox(item.id, item.value, item.textMode, item.mandatoryInput, item.maxLength,int.Parse(item.rowNumber), int.Parse(item.colNumber), item.visible, item.autoPostBack,item.enable, table);
}
```

CLASS

```
  public void CreateTextbox(String id, String value, String textMode, bool mandatoryInput
   , String maxLength, int rowNumber, int colNumber, bool visible, bool autopostBack, bool enable, Table table)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = id;
    tb.Text = value == null ? "" : value;
    tb.TextMode = textMode == null ? TextBoxMode.SingleLine : textMode.ToLower() == "multiline" ? TextBoxMode.MultiLine : TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
    tb.MaxLength = maxLength == null ? 32500 : int.Parse(maxLength);
    tb.Visible = visible;
    tb.Style.Add("width", "80%");
    tb.Enabled = enable;
    tb.AutoPostBack = autopostBack;

    tb.Font.Bold = true;
    tb.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Chocolate;

    tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb_TextChanged);
}

protected void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;

    tb.Text = //some values or display in another control in the form
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to listen to events yes.  Though dynamic controls should always be created during page preinit or page init, not load.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Please could you give me a simple illustration on how I can achieve it?

Comment: Move DynamicControls() method call to init